# Ordering arrays creation for two arrays with different arranged-arguments of arrays to apply on one of them to convert its orderings as another

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to rearrange each arrays (*`type = numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray`*) inside 'array1' (*`type = numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray`*) based on argument's order of each arrays (*`type = numpy.ndarray`*) of 'array2' (*`type = numpy.ndarray`*). Arrays by same indices inside each two bigger arrays have same arguments, but with unequal arrangements. I tried it before by using `array1[:, (0, 2, 1)]`, when all arrays inside array1 were needed to be rearranged based on one algorithm. But now, it is needed to rearrange each arrays inside array1 based on separate ordering algorithms derived from the corresponding arrays of array2.

It is needed to write some code such as `array1[:, (0, 2, 1)]`, but with an array [shape = array1.shape] containing ordering arrays in the form of `(0, 2, 1)`, which replace `(0, 2, 1)` in the sample above, to be applied on each arrays of array1.

**Note:** It is important to use code sample such above (preferring one-line), because this code will be used inside another third-party numerical software and by its built-in codes, in which array1's data will be return to the first state in each timestep and its masks may be updated in each timestep of the solution. That are called, repeatedly, by the built-in codes in each timestep.

For testing:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.ma.masked_array([np.array([20, 30, 35]), np.array([5, 6, 10]), np.array([11, 4, 7])], mask=False, fill_value=999999)
array2 = np.array([np.array([35, 20, 30]), np.array([10, 6, 5]), np.array([11, 7, 4])])
```

A modification array must be achieved based on array2 orderings for applying on array1 as:

```
mod_array = [(1, 2, 0), (2, 1, 0), (0, 2, 1)]
```

The results must be achieved by some code such as:

```
array1[:, mod_array]
```

Where each args in mod_array shows ordering and will be applied on each array1 corresponding arrays. Which will result in rearranging contained-arrays data of array1 masked_array:

```
array1 = np.ma.masked_array([np.array([35, 20, 30]), np.array([10, 6, 5]), np.array([11, 7, 4])], mask=..., fill_value=999999)
```

Comment: What's the dtype of these arrays, `object` or `int`?  In other words, is your `array2` the same as `array2 = np.array([[35, 20, 30], [10, 6, 5], [11, 7, 4]])`?

Comment: Yes it is @hpaulj

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 arrays:

```
In [189]: array1
Out[189]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[20, 30, 35],
        [5, 6, 10],
        [11, 4, 7]],
  mask=[[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],
  fill_value=999999)
In [190]: array2
Out[190]: 
array([[35, 20, 30],
       [10,  6,  5],
       [11,  7,  4]])
```

Your sorting index:

```
In [191]: idx=np.argsort(array2,axis=1)
In [192]: idx
Out[192]: 
array([[1, 2, 0],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 0]])
```

Applying that to `array2` shows that it orders each row:

```
In [193]: np.take_along_axis(array2, idx,1)
Out[193]: 
array([[20, 30, 35],
       [ 5,  6, 10],
       [ 4,  7, 11]])
```

Applied to `array1`:

```
In [194]: np.take_along_axis(array1, idx,1)
Out[194]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[30, 35, 20],
        [10, 6, 5],
        [7, 4, 11]],
  mask=[[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],
  fill_value=999999)
In [195]: idx=np.argsort(array1,axis=1)
```

To get your "desired" reorder, I have to reverse sort `array1`:

```
In [197]: idx=np.argsort(-array1,axis=1)
In [198]: np.take_along_axis(array1, idx,1)
Out[198]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[35, 30, 20],
        [10, 6, 5],
        [11, 7, 4]],
  mask=[[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],
  fill_value=999999)
```

Comment: Aim of the question is to ordering, not sorting. Actually, arrays of array1 must be rearranged to become as array2.  Final data must be = [[35,20,30],[10, 6, 5],[11, 7, 4]], and idx must be as the mod_array. For example: mod_array[0]=[1, 2, 0], which will applied on array1[0], shows that array1[0][0] must be placed instead of current array1[0][1] (mod_array[0][0]=1 shows the index which that arg must be at) and mod_array[0][1] (which is '2') and mod_array[0][2] (which is '0') show that array1[0][1] and array1[0][2] must be placed instead of current array1[0][2] and array1[0][0], respectively.